# Exclude blacklisted exact routes on React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a `Navbar` component which I want to display on every route except `/login` and `/`. I tried doing the following:

```
<Route path="!(/|/login)*" component={Navbar} />
```

However, since `/` will match pretty much every route when not exact, it will pretty much never render.

How could I blacklist a few paths for rendering a component?

Answer (score 0):

Blacklist: `/`, `/login`

```
 <Route path={/^\/(?!login)./} component={Component} />
```